# Too much Wireframe

Tags: vertices, wireframe

I want to know does having too much wireframe is bad for your model?
my model doesn't have too many vertices but when i toggle wireframe mode i see millions of  wireframes ( i have unsubdivide my model because it had too many vertices and used subdivision surface and increased views to 4 to correct my model)
and if is bad how i must fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enable the ***Optimal Display***  option. Check the *Optimal Display* checkbox in the *Subsurf* modifier panel.
[image]